# Sorting dictionary by truple value date object

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have following dictionary I would like to sort it by date object in the truple

```
final_dict={'102 Not Out': "('75', '2018-05-04 00:00:00'),N/A",
'2.0': "('84', '2019-01-01 00:00:00'),8.5",
'3 Dev': "('0', '2018-05-11 00:00:00'),No IMDB Info Available",
'Adityam': "('34', '2018-04-27 00:00:00'),No IMDB Info Available",
'Ajay Devgn – Luv Ranjan’s Next': "('63', '2018-10-19 00:00:00'),No IMDB Info Available",
'Arjun Patiala': "('0', '2018-09-13 00:00:00'),No IMDB Info Available",
'Baazaar': "('60', '2018-05-01 00:00:00'),N/A"}
```

I have following code but its not working - It only sorts dictionary by key,

```
OrderedDict(sorted(final_dict.items(), key=lambda t: t[0]))

OR

sorted(final_dict.items(),key=lambda x: x[1][2])
```

Looking for following output:

```
{'Adityam': "('34', '2018-04-27 00:00:00'),No IMDB Info Available",
'Baazaar': "('60', '2018-05-01 00:00:00'),N/A",
'102 Not Out': "('75', '2018-05-04 00:00:00'),N/A",
'3 Dev': "('0', '2018-05-11 00:00:00'),No IMDB Info Available",
'Arjun Patiala': "('0', '2018-09-13 00:00:00'),No IMDB Info Available",
'Ajay Devgn – Luv Ranjan’s Next': "('63', '2018-10-19 00:00:00'),No IMDB Info Available",
'2.0': "('84', '2019-01-01 00:00:00'),8.5",
}
```

can somebody please assist?

Comment: How did you arrive at such messy input? The *best* solution is to fix this before you even arrive at the dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way using `collections.OrderedDict` and `ast.literal_eval`.

As noted, it's best, if possible, to resolve these issues before the data reaches a dictionary.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from ast import literal_eval

res = OrderedDict(sorted(final_dict.items(),
                  key=lambda x: literal_eval(x[1].split('),')[0]+')')[1]))
```

Result:

```
OrderedDict([('Adityam', "('34', '2018-04-27 00:00:00'),No IMDB Info Available"),
             ('Baazaar', "('60', '2018-05-01 00:00:00'),N/A"),
             ('102 Not Out', "('75', '2018-05-04 00:00:00'),N/A"),
             ('3 Dev', "('0', '2018-05-11 00:00:00'),No IMDB Info Available"),
             ('Arjun Patiala', "('0', '2018-09-13 00:00:00'),No IMDB Info Available"),
             ('Ajay Devgn – Luv Ranjan’s Next', "('63', '2018-10-19 00:00:00'),No IMDB Info Available"),
             ('2.0', "('84', '2019-01-01 00:00:00'),8.5")])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ast.literal_eval`:

```
import ast
import collections
import re
final_dict={'102 Not Out': "('75', '2018-05-04 00:00:00'),N/A",'2.0': "('84', '2019-01-01 00:00:00'),8.5", '3 Dev': "('0', '2018-05-11 00:00:00'),No IMDB Info Available",'Adityam': "('34', '2018-04-27 00:00:00'),No IMDB Info Available",'Ajay Devgn – Luv Ranjan’s Next': "('63', '2018-10-19 00:00:00'),No IMDB Info Available", 'Arjun Patiala': "('0', '2018-09-13 00:00:00'),No IMDB Info Available",'Baazaar': "('60', '2018-05-01 00:00:00'),N/A"}
new_data = sorted(final_dict.items(), key=lambda x:list(map(int, ast.literal_eval(re.sub('(?<=\))[\w\W]+', '', x[-1]))[-1].split()[0].split('-'))))
final_data = collections.OrderedDict(new_data)
```

Output:

```
OrderedDict([('Adityam', "('34', '2018-04-27 00:00:00'),No IMDB Info Available"), 
('Baazaar', "('60', '2018-05-01 00:00:00'),N/A"), 
('102 Not Out', "('75', '2018-05-04 00:00:00'),N/A"), ('3 Dev', "('0', '2018-05-11 00:00:00'),No IMDB Info Available"), 
('Arjun Patiala', "('0', '2018-09-13 00:00:00'),No IMDB Info Available"), 
('Ajay Devgn \xe2\x80\x93 Luv Ranjan\xe2\x80\x99s Next', "('63', '2018-10-19 00:00:00'),No IMDB Info Available"), 
('2.0', "('84', '2019-01-01 00:00:00'),8.5")])
```

Comment: Getting error: new_data = sorted(final_dict.items(), key=lambda x:list(map(int, ast.literal_eval(re.sub('(?<=\))[\w\W]+', '', x[-1]))[-1].split()[0].split('-'))))
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: @spider22: Are you sure you are using the same data that you posted? I tested this in both Python2 and Python3 and it worked correctly.

Comment: data is same just large, however, I had this issue before with list object not callable. In my code its give error - If I take out of my code on the same server and create a new script it works fine. very strange ...

Comment: @spider22 Perhaps the data is being mutated before the code above is run?

Comment: This is before that -     
    results=getdetails(movies_D)
    #pprint.pprint(results)
    temp_dict = {results[i]:results[i+1] for i in range(0, len(results), 2)}
    final_dict = {a:"{},{}".format(b, temp_dict[a]) for a, b in movies_D.items()}

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you should use datetime module with neat solution in just one line :

```
import datetime

print(sorted(final_dict.items(),key=lambda x:datetime.datetime.strptime(x[1].split()[1].replace("'",''),'%Y-%m-%d')))
```

output:

```
[('Adityam', "('34', '2018-04-27 00:00:00'),No IMDB Info Available"), ('Baazaar', "('60', '2018-05-01 00:00:00'),N/A"), ('102 Not Out', "('75', '2018-05-04 00:00:00'),N/A"), ('3 Dev', "('0', '2018-05-11 00:00:00'),No IMDB Info Available"), ('Arjun Patiala', "('0', '2018-09-13 00:00:00'),No IMDB Info Available"), ('Ajay Devgn – Luv Ranjan’s Next', "('63', '2018-10-19 00:00:00'),No IMDB Info Available"), ('2.0', "('84', '2019-01-01 00:00:00'),8.5")]
```

Comment: This is the better way to go vs. `ast_literal`